# Convert a SQLAlchemy object into JSON or Python dictionary

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I can't find a no-nonsense way to do something trivial. When queries get complicated I find it easier to write them in plain old SQL:

```
q = 'SELECT...'
entries = db.session.execute(q)
```

which gives me back an `<class 'sqlalchemy.engine.result.ResultProxy'>` object.

At this point I'd like to treat this object like a python list, maybe do some `jsonify(entries)` and alike, but none of these work outside the box.

Googling around returned me a whole mess of hacky solutions so I'm just begging for the nice one here.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest would be to use some kind of object marshalling library eg. [Marshmallow](http://marshmallow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), but by far it's not a one-shot solution.